# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Mongoose + Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I submit my content it shows *ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*. In my node console, it shows me the Error: *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*. When I restart my server message content field will show. In my database, the message model has content value but users model has no **message id**.

I am using Mongoose 5.0.0.
when check my db it shows **messages=[]**

```
db.users.find()
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5a771f08ee207b13808a2599"), "firstName" : "rakib", "lastName" : "vai", "password" : "$2a$10$kCGCyFOPCedZcs.4Y6D.Huq02aYycuEssj5suTh00bRJSCGw1N3VO", "email" : "xxxxxx@gmail.com", "messages" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

In my messages collection show like this

```
db.messages.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a771f20ee207b13808a259a"), "content" : "rakibvai", "user" : ObjectId("5a771f08ee207b13808a2599"), "__v" : 0 }
```

My **message model** file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = require('./user');

var schema = new Schema({
 content: {type: String, required: true},
 user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
 });

 schema.post('remove', function (message) {
   User.findById(message.user, function (err, user) {
    user.messages.pull(message);
    user.save();
     });
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', schema);
```

And **my user model file**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var schema = new Schema({
   firstName: {type: String, required: true},
   lastName: {type: String, required: true},
   password: {type: String, required: true},
   email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
   messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]

     });
 schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

 module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**my message.js route**

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occurred',
            error: err
        });
    }
    var message = new Message({
        content: req.body.content,
        user: user
    });
    message.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        user.messages.push(result);
        user.save();
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            obj: result
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify, what content do you submit and what function do you call?

Comment: message content field in message model.

Comment: the result object is with $ sign in bson don't push this into messages, try like this : 
`user.messages.push(result._doc)`